# Manipulating Drop Shadow/Layering of Shapes: Adobe Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, layers, drop-shadow

Never used a help forum before, but with a looming deadline, I am very open to all the help I can get!

I am relatively inexperienced with Illustrator (most of my knowledge comes from searching up information on Youtube, and from trying to carry over knowledge of InDesign).

I am trying to apply a drop shadow to my shapes in the first image (I created them using pen tool and shape builder tool, just as I did for the second image's 'waves'), but am having trouble with the layering. In the second photo, I've achieved a consistent shadow, but when I try to apply the same effect to the first image (the foot shape that radiates outward), it appears as though one of the layers is under the middle layer. I cannot figure out how to undo this, whether I need to redo everything (which I already have, and it didn't change anything) or make the drop shadow apply to only one side... any help would be much appreciated!

[image]
[image]

Comment: guessing.. it would appear that rather than having an *actual shape* for that middle she, you need to cut the shape out of the layer below it...  So the light green/teal has a *hole* in it, as opposed to a shape on top of it.

Comment: The drop shadows appear in layer stacking order. But seems like you have a compound path with a hole. Only way to be sure is by you showing a expanded view of your layers panel. (But by the time you do you have probably solved this allready since you now undertand how it works)

Comment: Thank you all! I'm not sure exactly what the problem was, but I believe that my rectangle around the border of the image had some anchor points deleted, so once I restored these I was able to successfully complete all the shapes and then just layer them by sending to back, etc. Thanks so much!